# how do I find the values that are in one column but not in the other

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns A and B in a google spreadsheet.

I want to find all the numbers that are in column A but not in B. How do I do that?

B could have the same numbers from column A.

So if column A has numbers: 1, 2, 3
and B has numbers 3, 4,5

I want to get all the numbers that are in A but not in B:
1, 2

How do I do that using google spread sheet?

Answer (score 79):

Use [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) to determine whether each row in column A appears in column B, then filter column A to only the rows for which [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) returned `#N/A` (i.e., that row's value in column A could not be found in column B):

```
=FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0)))
```

If A contains duplicates and you want to reduce the result sequence to unique values, just wrap the whole thing in [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198):

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0))))
```

Comment: This may work back then, now I need to use ISNA instead of ISERROR.

Comment: [`ISNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093293) is more specific,  and therefore probably a better choice (will update), but [`ISERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349) does still work in Google Sheets. [`ISERR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093348) will not work, however, as it returns `FALSE` on `#N/A` -- perhaps that's what you tried?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: @Kate great! This works for the whole rows of `A` and `B`, but how put the results in a new column `C`?

Comment: I tried the solution given in this thread with no luck. Then I came across an alternative with a minor `{}` tweak and that worked.

For example:
```=UNIQUE(FILTER({A:A}, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0))))```

Here's a reference to the solution I picked this from:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10882571/results-that-match-and-do-not-match?hl=en

Answer (score 12):

Based on Kate aswer I have been able to negate not only one column, but several.

Kate solution was as follows:

> =FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0)))

Where "B:B" is defining that what is going to be returned is A:A less B:B.

But if you want to return A:A, lees B:B, less C:C, less D:D, etc? 
Just insert B:B, C:C and D:D inside {}, then:

```
=FILTER(A:A; ISNA(MATCH(A:A; {B:B;C:C;D:D}; 0)))
```

I hope this may help others like me. I was seeking for a solution that would not bring what's present in some set of columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In column C, use vlookup from A against B. For example

```
C1 = vlookup(A1,B:B,1)
C2 = vlookup(A2,B:B,1)
...
```

If B does not contain A, then it shows `#N/A`