# Comparing 2 Ranges in Google Sheets and return values that are not in first range

Tags: google-sheets

I got 2 Ranges:

[Ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXa5n.jpg)

Main Range:

```
2345
3456
7890
Hello
```

2nd Range:

```
2345
3456
```

The second range is received by certain mechanisms (which is not relevant at this point).

And now I would like to receive a list of items that is sort of the subtraction between the main range and the second range.

So the result should be something like:

```
7890
Hello
```

How can I approach this?

I would try to avoid using querying for all values individually but sort of a filter array for values in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do use:

`=FILTER(A:A, ISERROR(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0)))`

Sample output:

[image: output]

Comment: Alternatively OP could try: `=FILTER(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,B:B)=0)`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in another thread on stack overflow.

[Thread] :[how do I find the values that are in one column but not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442475/how-do-i-find-the-values-that-are-in-one-column-but-not-in-the-other)

```
=FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0)))
```

This solution works with strings and numbers equally

There is another solution that did not workout fully for my issue because I have strings and numbers but for text this one seems also to be fine after some testing.

```
=filter(Y14:Y, REGEXMATCH(Y14:Y,join("|",Z14:Z)))
```

Question can be closed but for people that do not use the right search terms as I did, maybe this still helps

Comment: Glad you were still able to find what works for you. Kudos