# VLOOKUP errors- just can't get what I'm looking for.... "Did not find value error"

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, google-forms

I hope this is easy enough to understand the objective of. I'm trying to pull the names (by email username) of everyone who nominated a particular student for quarterly awards.

I'm working on a spreadsheet that will be populated from a Google form.  The form has a single question- "Who do you want to nominate?" with about 120 choices. The spreadsheet puts this into tab 1 with 3 columns: timestamp, email of user, all nominated names by that user in 1 cell.

Tab 2 (NAMES_SEPERATE!) copies over the nominated names into column A, user's email address into column B and splits the nomination names into single columns C-AA.

Tab 3 where I want the final results has:

- column A with all the possible nominations
- column B where I want it to show the email of each user who nominated that person
  =vlookup(A2, {NAMES_SEPERATE!B:AA, NAMES_SEPERATE!B:B}, 2, true)

I get "did not find value 'John Smith' in VLOOKUP evaluation (but it should have found it 3 times from the existing entries. If I change the above to look at columns C:AA to search for the names and skip the column with the user's email address then I will get a result as long as I ask for a column between C and AA to pull that result.  That gives me another nomination name but from the same line that the one I am looking for is from.

Can anyone help? This would make our student reward assembly ever quarter sao much easier to calculate out.  Thank you!!

I tried researching the problem and I've made progress but I cannot get there.  Initially I was getting errors that it cannot be text and must be a number. I've spent 2 hours trying to get this to work and I have classes in between. This will take days at this rate so I'm calling uncle and asking for help.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: `column B where I want it to show the email of each user who nominated that person` Please provide an example of the expected output. The question is unclear on this aspect  and there are many possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of nominees and their respective nominators based on a Google Form survey.

The key elements of this answer have already been documented in StackOverflow questions

- [building a new list by separating comma separated values while retaining adjacent row values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63930198/1330560)
- [creating a new list of comma separated values with common row values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323648/1330560)

---

Try this:

**Tab2 (Sheet : NAMES_SEPERATE01) (strictly optional)**

- Manually enter headers in cell A1 & B1
- Enter this formula in Cell A2:

`=query({'Form Responses 1'!B2:C},"select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null")`

**Tab2 (Sheet : NAMES_SEPERATE02)**

- Manually enter headers in cell A1 & B1
- Enter this formula in Cell A2:

`=ArrayFormula( SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT( JOIN( "", BYROW( query({'Form Responses 1'!B2:C},"select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null") , LAMBDA(row, JOIN( ",", REDUCE( ";", row, LAMBDA(cell1,cell2, FLATTEN(FLATTEN(cell1)&","&SPLIT(cell2,",")) ) ) ) ) ) ), ";,",)),",") )`

h/t: @GeneralGrievance` : [How do you separate comma separated values in different columns while maintaining values in the rest of the row in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63930198/1330560)

**Tab3 (Sheet: Results)**

- Manually enter headers in cell A1 & B1
- Enter this formula in Cell A2:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({NAMES_SEPERATE02!B2:B&"×", NAMES_SEPERATE02!A2:A&",", ROW(NAMES_SEPERATE02!B2:B)},  "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))`

### h/t: @player0 - [How to create a comma separate aggregate in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323648/1330560)

**Sample: Sheet: Results**

[image: results]

---

**Sample: Sheet: NAMES_SEPARATE02**

[image: names02]

---

**Sample: Sheet: NAMES_SEPARATE01 (Optional)**

[image: names01]

---

**Sample: Sheet: Form Responses 1**

[image: forms]

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz- Thank you for your wisdom.  I've tried applying your edits.  They seem operational but I need the data to look different on the results tab.  I need all students names there even if they don't get nominated (so I just copied them all in Column A) and then in the columns to the right I need the emails of any teacher that nominated them to appear 1 per column in a row for that student.  Students with no noimnations won't return any results in their row.

Comment: Here's a link to a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lC83VXQLBvLYDimSbGMgk3RwuLcvzs5t4w3708ahXs8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also- we had a snowday Friday so I'm just returning to this project and appreciate your help.

Comment: `both emails should be listed here (1 per column) so a row of all emails who nominated come after the student's name` There shouldn't be a problem "splitting" the nominator email addresses BUT... are you trying t get the each nominator to have a unique column?

Comment: Thank you- I'm sorry. IDK what happened earlier but I do have it correct now and the entries are horizontal.  I would love it if each nominator went into a separate column but not a requirement..  I'd really like all students names to be listed though, even if they aren't nominated (and so then they'd have no entries next to their name.  Can you work your magic on that last piece and the rest is pretty as a picture?

Comment: `I do have it correct now and the entries are horizontal.` Not sure what that means, please edit your sample spreadsheet to show your result. `I'd really like all students names to be listed though,` Again, not sure what this means. Please provide an example (RESULTS02??) on your spreadsheet.

Comment: Apologies. Sample updated.  The names on "RESULTS" in yellow are options to nominate in the form but no one nominated them.  I'd like them to appear in the results but with no names of nominators next to them.

Comment: Also- I'm interested in creating conditional formatting on the results page to change the cell or font color of a small number of the nominators.  To do that they'd need to be in a separate cell for each nominator.  Still not critical but would make it better.

Comment: `Also- I'm interested in` Let's not stretch the friendship, eh.

Comment: [how do I find the values that are in one column but not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606189/1330560) - `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0))))` This will generate a list of the names not nominated. It is non-trivial to amend the entire answer for this; I suggest that you just paste the list at the bottom of the nominees.

Comment: @ConnieMarkowicz If you think that this is a good answer, then perhaps you would consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)